# Mvvm cross 3.5 binding Show warring

Tags: binding, mvvmcross

After updating my project to Unified API and MVVM Cross 3.5 stable ,I am getting the following warring message in the console for all button bindings...

I am binding like this.

```
try {
 this.AddBindings(
  new Dictionary < object, string > () {

   //all the command controls - such as buttons
   {
    btnXmit,
    "TouchUpInside cmdXmitClicked"
   }, {
    btnCancel,
    "TouchUpInside cmdBack"
   },

  });
} catch (Exception error) {

}
```

at

> Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2[System.Windows.Input.ICommand,System.EventArgs]..ctor (ICommand source, System.Reflection.EventInfo sourceEventInfo, System.EventHandler`1 targetEventHandler) [0x00028] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription/MvxWeakEventSubscription.cs:52 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxCanExecuteChangedEventSubscription..ctor (ICommand source, System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler) [0x00000] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription/MvxCanExecuteChangedEventSubscription.cs:21 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe (ICommand source, System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler) [0x00003] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription/MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.cs:68 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.Target.MvxUIControlTouchUpInsideTargetBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x00045] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Target/MvxUIControlTouchUpInsideTargetBinding.cs:74 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x000bd] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Bindings/Target/MvxConvertingTargetBinding.cs:64 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00036] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Bindings/MvxFullBinding.cs:162 
>   2015-02-16 17:48:14.433 RemoteInspectioniOS[3506:119564] MvxBind: Error: 212.37 Problem seen during binding execution for binding TouchUpInside for cmdBack - problem ArgumentNullException: missing source event info in MvxWeakEventSubscription
>   Parameter name: sourceEventInfo
>         at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2[System.Windows.Input.ICommand,System.EventArgs]..ctor (ICommand source, System.Reflection.EventInfo sourceEventInfo, System.EventHandler`1 targetEventHandler) [0x00028] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription/MvxWeakEventSubscription.cs:52 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxCanExecuteChangedEventSubscription..ctor (ICommand source, System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler) [0x00000] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription/MvxCanExecuteChangedEventSubscription.cs:21 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.WeakSubscribe (ICommand source, System.EventHandler`1 eventHandler) [0x00003] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/WeakSubscription/MvxWeakSubscriptionExtensionMethods.cs:68 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.Target.MvxUIControlTouchUpInsideTargetBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x00045] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Target/MvxUIControlTouchUpInsideTargetBinding.cs:74 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x000bd] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Bindings/Target/MvxConvertingTargetBinding.cs:64 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00036] in /Volumes/WORKSPACE/Workspace/V3.5/framework/framework/MvvmCross-3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Bindings/MvxFullBinding.cs:162

Comment: Please reformat your "error message", it's almost unusable !

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427201/binding-to-text-property-ios-unified-not-working

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to create a LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file with the following code:

```
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(ICommand command)
    {
        command.CanExecuteChanged += (s, e) => { if (command.CanExecute(null)) command.Execute(null); };
    }
}
```

EDIT (per my comment):

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply... It would be helpful for me if i know where i need to include this class.

Comment: You just need to add it to your iOS project.