# Binding MvvmCross UITextView TextColor

Tags: xamarin, uitextview, mvvmcross

Ported my Xamarin iOS app to the unified api. I'm using MvvmCross and I can no longer bind to `TextColor` with a `UITextView`. I receive the following warning:

> MvxBind:Warning: 39.30 Failed to create target binding for binding
>   TextColor for EditableTextColour

My view:

```
set.Bind(userPromptTextView).For(up => up.BackgroundColor).To(vm => vm.EditableBackgroundColour);
set.Bind(userPromptTextView).For(up => up.TextColor).To(vm => vm.EditableTextColour);
```

ViewModel:

```
public UIKit.UIColor EditableTextColour
{
    get
    {
        return Question.IsEditable ? UIKit.UIColor.Black : UIKit.UIColor.Black.ColorWithAlpha(0.5f);
    }
}
```

Note that `BackgroundColor` binds correctly, although I believe that is binding to `UIView`.

I'm using MvvmCross 3.5.1-alpha1 and testing on an iPad (iOS 8.1.3).

NuGet packages

```
  <package id="MvvmCross" version="3.5.1-alpha1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore" version="3.5.1-alpha1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries" version="3.5.1-alpha1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Color" version="3.5.1-alpha1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Visibility" version="3.5.1-alpha1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack" version="3.5.1-alpha1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.PortableSupport" version="3.5.1-alpha1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
```

Comment: Are there any additional warnings or log messages? Can you check you are using `MvvmCross 3.5.1-alpha1`? and how are you `testing on an Android device`?

Comment: Sorry @Stuart I meant iPad. I've been doing a lot of Android work lately. I'm fairly certain I'm using 3.5.1-alpha1 (I've added NuGet packages above) although there are still references to 3.2.1 in my packages folder. My application builds a form dynamically so I isolated a page to only contain the above control and that is the only warning I get. I have a lot of other bindings and this is the only issue I have encountered.

Comment: So I had some references to 3.2.1 in another project which I have now updated. There are now no references to 3.2.1 at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will answer your question: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/902

I had the same issue but with boolean-binding of a UILabel and UIView element. A simple workaround is to just declare the UI-Element as a `private property` in your class (in your case: `userPromptTextView`).

With this workaround, the GC won't eliminate your element and the binding should work.

Additional info: [Is this a bug in MonoTouch GC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058521/is-this-a-bug-in-monotouch-gc/13059140#13059140)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no luck there. Although you can't tell from my sample, `userPromptTextView` was a local variable which I moved to a private property of the view. I still receive the above warning.